# VS/EF ignores MSSQLLocalDB setting in App.config

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, connection-string

I had previously installed SQL Server 2008 R2, and VS 2015. I was creating some console apps using EF (6.1.3), and added a connection string as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=EFTest2.mdf;Initial Catalog=EFTest2;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

A database was correctly being created under the `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB` instance (v12.0.2000)

(Although I noticed 2 peculiarities:

1. If I renamed the database in the connection string, EF did not create a new db with the new name, and
2. EF automatically appends the context name to the DB file, e.g. `EFTest2.MyContext.mdf`. These may relate to the current question....)

Then I installed SQL Server 2014 and Tools (SSMS). After restart PC, now if I use the same connection string as above, the database gets created under `USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS` (v10.0.2531). So VS ignores the `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB` part, but still creates the DB with the name specified in the connection string.

Can anyone explain this?

(I am created the `DbContext` without specifying a connection string. I found that if I specify the connection string, then VS follows all info included in the connection string)

Comment: First of all, are you sure you have an instance of LocalDb installed with an instance name of MSSQLLocalDB?  You can look in the SQL Server Object Explorer for the instance

Comment: Yes, indeed. Also, if I type `sqllocaldb i` into PM Console, I get `MSSQLLocalDB, ProjectsV12, v11.0`. I do not even get a result for v10.0.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue and in my case it turns our entity framework adds its own additional configuration where it has the instance name:

```
entityFramework/defaultConnectionFactory
```

It doesn't make sense to me why would it add this when the istance name is specified in the connection string but if the isntance name in this section is different then it would use that and not the localdb instace name from your connection string.